# Facebook embbeding Iframe on friends wall

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-apps

I am primarly ASP.NET(HTML,Js) programmer and I don't know anything about Fb apps. Recently I stumbled on a problem. I have web application that generates image buttons and generates code as HTML or Iframe for user to post on different websites, however as far as I know: It is not possible for user to embbed Iframe or post image wrapped with link to friends wall?

So before I start researching how to do anything on Facebook and go on wild goose chase, I just wanted to check with fellow programmers that might have experiences with this kind of stuff is it even possible to do this on Facebook?

If it is possible, can you give me some hints how the process goes or point me to some articles?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to post iframes to a user's wall.

To be more specific, to post to a wall, we use [Feed dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) (with `FB.ui`), You can derive what you can and can't do from the list of parameters that `FB.ui` gets (scroll to "properties" in the feed dialog doc)

To show the "post to wall" dialog, you need to do something like this:

```
FB.ui({ 
    method: 'feed',
    link: "link",
    picture: "picture",
    name: "name",
    caption: "caption", 
    description: "description"
}, callback);
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I understood it without problem, I imagine such code with properties: From and To would do something like User > Friend and then the post contents?

Comment: Yes, in fact, it is explicitly explained in the doc.